# Pyinstaller for arm 32bit compilation

Tags: pyinstaller

I am using Ubuntu as a host system,.compiled for 32bit manually chosen the bootloader, with respect to that create bundle Python file. And copy into my arm target board.

The error which I am facing is  not able to execute the binary file 
In my arm board.

I cannot able to bundle .my .csv files with executable using `--add-data`. While running the executable, it searches my CSV file in the current folder, it shows error as file not found error.
how to add multiple files (CSV and INI) files with my executable.

How to fix this issue.

Regards
Rajalakshmi

Comment: Can you post your full error log and your bootloader? Also, what is your arm board? It is easier to simulate your arm board OS and build your app inside it instead of cross-compiling it.

Comment: Hi ,i can able to compile with debian rootfs.. thanks for your support ..But i cannot able to bundle .my .csv files with executable using --add-data . While running executable ,it searches my csv file in current folder .. it shows error as file not found error error 2 ..please solve this issue. how to add multiple files of csv and ini files with my executable..

Comment: Your question varied, I edited the question and now answering it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding data files you need to First, provide your data files with [`--add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag. Then because your data would be extracted on a temp directory, you need to set its address for your app. In below example, I'm addressing all CSV files from `resource_path` function which would return the relative path for each file.

I assume that you put all your files in `data` directory beside your app.

`app.py`:

```
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_files = ["data/a.csv", "data/b.csv", "data/c.csv"]

    print("Reading CSV files from data directory")
    for csv_file in csv_files:
        with open(resource_path(csv_file), "r") as f:
            print(csv_files, ":", f.read())
    print("Done!")
```

You can then generate your executable with:

```
pyinstaller app.py -F --add-data "./data/*;data/"
```

Comment: Calling another script from Subprocess  is not working with pyinstaller.. no such file or directoryerror is showing.how to solve this

Comment: Please ask your question as a new question with more details.